# method cursor in trait GenericQueryBuilder is deprecated

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I'm working with `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.7.play24"` and when i compile my proyect, show me the next errors:

```
[error] /home/hector/enova/play-silhouette-reactivemongo-seed-master/app/controllers/CourseController.scala:90: method cursor in trait GenericQueryBuilder is deprecated: Use [[cursor]] function with read preference.
[error]       cursor[JsObject]
[error]       ^
[error] /home/hector/enova/play-silhouette-reactivemongo-seed-master/app/controllers/CourseController.scala:120: method cursor in trait GenericQueryBuilder is deprecated: Use [[cursor]] function with read preference.
[error]       cursor[JsObject]
[error]       ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

The lines 90 and 120 are are in bold:

```
    val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collection.
      find(Json.obj("title" -> title)).
      sort(Json.obj("created" -> -1)).       
      cursor[JsObject]


    val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collection.
      find(Json.obj("active" -> true)).
      cursor[JsObject]
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add parentheses to `cursor` method. This will be work.

```
collection.find(...).cursor[JsObject]()
```